# How to auto display the sum of two buttons with a number value in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I can't find some similar questions here same with my problem.
Could someone help me to auto add two numbers by clicking the "book" button with a number value? and display the total in `<h1 id="total">Total</h1>`?

This is my HTML code:

```
            <div class="left-container" style="width: 50%; float: left">
        <h2>Left</h2>   
            <div class="each-container">
                <p class="name">Name 1</p>
                <p class="price">1111.00</p>
                <button class="book1" value="1111.00">book</button>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="each-container">
                <p class="name">Name 2</p>
                <p class="price">2222.00</p>
                <button class="book1" value="2222.00">book</button>
            </div>
            <h1 id="feedback1">feedback1</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="right-container" style="width: 50%; float: right">
        <h2>Right</h2>  
            <div class="each-container">
                <p class="name">Name 1</p>
                <p class="price">1111.00</p>
                <button class="book2" value="1111.00">book</button>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="each-container">
                <p class="name">Name 2</p>
                <p class="price">2222.00</p>
                <button class="book2" value="2222.00">book</button>
            </div>

            <h1 id="feedback2">feedback2</h1>
        </div>
            <h1 id="total">Total</h1>
```

And this my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.book1').click(function (){
        var price1 = $(this).attr('value');
        $('#feedback1').text(price1);
    });
    $('.book2').click(function (){
        var price2 = $(this).attr('value');
        $('#feedback2').text(price2);
    });

    var feedback1 = $('#feedback1').text();
    var feedback2 = $('#feedback2').text();
    var total = feedback1 + feedback2;
    $('#total').text(total);

});
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

convert feedback1 and 2 to int before u add them

```
var total = parseInt(feedback1) + parseInt(feedback2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the values inside `#feedback1` and `#feedback2` are generated dynamically, you need to recalculate `total` every time any button is clicked. So it's best to abstract it into a function, which can also check if the values inside both are numbers or not (using only `parseInt` can return `NaN` which cannot be added to):

```
    function updateTotal(){
        var feedback1 = !isNaN(parseInt($('#feedback1').text())) ? parseFloat($('#feedback1').text()) : 0;
        var feedback2 = !isNaN(parseInt($('#feedback2').text())) ? parseFloat($('#feedback2').text()) : 0;
        var total = (feedback1 + feedback2).toFixed(2);
        $('#total').text(total);
    }
```

Now you can call this function at the end of both of your click handlers (for `#book1` and `#book2`):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.book1').click(function (){
            var price1 = $(this).attr('value');
            $('#feedback1').text(price1);
            updateTotal();
        });
        $('.book2').click(function (){
            var price2 = $(this).attr('value');
            $('#feedback2').text(price2);
            updateTotal();
        });
    });
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mudrrysL/

Comment: Thank you very much @Sidd that works really great, but last how about the two decimal value, for example the first number is 1111.01 and second is 2222.03 how can I get the total of 3333.03? I try to change the parseInt to parseFloat but it didn't work.  Thank you again Sidd :)

Comment: In addition to using parseFloat in getting the values of _feedback1_ and _feedback2_, you would need to use the _toFixed_ method on _total_ and pass it an argument of 2 (the number of decimal points you want the sum to contain). See my edited _updateTotal_ function. Note that this will make the value of _total_ a string, so if you want to use it as a number in some calculation later you'll need to use a parseFloat on it too.

Comment: Hi @Sidd Im so sorry for now Im not capable to upvote coz I have not enough reputation yet, sooner I'll be back here to upvote. THANKS!